# How to get model array after angularjs drag and drop?

Tags: angularjs

I have a list in which data is filled as such:

```
<ul ui-sortable="sortableOptions" ng-model="hiringstagelist" class="sortable list">
                                            <li ng-repeat="y in hiringstagelist">  
                                                <div class="row">
                                                    <div class="col-md-1">
                                                        <label class="switch">
                                                            <input id="{{y.id}}" class="switch-input" type="checkbox" ng-model="y.isDeleted" ng-click="deletehiringstage(y.id)" />
                                                            <span id="data_{{y.id}}" class="switch-label" data-on="" data-off=""></span>
                                                            <span class="switch-handle"></span>
                                                        </label>
                                                    </div>

                                                        <div class="col-md-11">
                                                            {{y.stageName}}
                                                            <span style="float:right;margin-right:10px;"><img src="~/Images/sortarrow.png" /></span>
                                                        </div>
                                                    </div>
                                                   </li>                                        




                                    </ul>
```

As I'm using angularjs drag and drop hence as soon as I drag and drop any item in the list an event gets triggered which is :

```
$scope.sortableOptions = {
            stop: function (e, ui) {

                var model = ui.item.model;
                console.log(model);

                var index = ui.item.sortable.index;
                var draggedModel = ui.item.sortable.model;


                var newProdArray = ui.item.sortable.resort.$modelValue;


            }

        }
```

With index I only get the old value of the item in the list. "newProdArray" doesn't seems to work. Can i use anything so that i can get a model with new index values along with other parameters od the item like id etc ?

Please guide

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you want `ui.item.sortable.dropindex` which gives you the index the item was dropped at. See [here](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-sortable/blob/c66dd9410acad4a3e5fa44a69b0095cd8b5031d2/API.md#dropindex) for documentation.

Comment: HI sophie. So can't I get the whole list with new indexes ?

Comment: I got the required model using ui.item.sortable.droptargetModel; Thanks .